# I want to set a variable value in first iteration of for each loop php 5.2

Tags: php, foreach

```
$firstbooking=true;
@foreach($upcomingOrder->bookings as $booking)
    ....
    If($firstbooking)
    {
    ...
    $firstbooking=false;
    }

@endforeach
```

I have tried this. It is working but Can someone suggest different way to do this?

Comment: It is good enough, you don't need to search for alternatives. Go to the next task.

Comment: BTW, PHP `5.2` are you sure you want to work on such an old and buggy version? I'd suggest using at least some of the newest versions of the `7.x` branch.

Comment: `@foreach...` are you using Laravel? Look into the `$loop` variable - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but the syntax you're using looks like Blade templating. If so, you can use the `$loop` variable.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable

```
@foreach($upcomingOrder->bookings as $booking)
    if ($loop->first) {
        ...
    }

@endforeach
```